# Nexus 7 does not have Google Play app installed

Tags: google, nexus-7

A Nexus 7 tablet having android 4.4.2, does not have the default Google Play(neither older Android market) app installed.How is that possible?

I tried downloading *.apk file from [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/05/07/apk-download-google-play-services-updated-to-v4-4-with-new-street-view-api-running-detection-and-more/) and even [here](http://www.android.gs/download-google-play-store-apk-4-4-22/)
But did not work. When I tried executing the apk file, they hang and I get "ANR - application not responding" dialog.

For other *.apk files for Google store app that i downloaded, it gave errors saying Error saying  - "There was a problem parsing the package".  It just did not work for many Google store apk's different versions i tried downloading and installing/running?

How can one install Google play store on this Nexus 7?

Would there be any correct/compatible *.apk for Google play store available which would work?

Edit Note: I tried checking in settings and elsewhere to see if any default apps disabled setting is checked but could not find any such thing?

Comment: Who sold you the tablet? Get a refund.

Comment: Sounds like whoever sold it to you might have installed a custom rom at some point.. (or probably STILL on custom rom)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing happen on a 3 year old phone I hadn't used in a long time.  Android appears (at least in some cases) to be unable to upgrade from some old versions without installing the versions inbetween, which is of course impossible in most cases.  While in my case the store appeared to be available, it didn't work at all.  I ended up doing a complete factory reset to get up to date.  I wouldn't expect this situation on a Nexus 7, but if you don't have a ton of data on it, you might try a factory reset.

Comment: Factory reset wont work for getting the Play Store back, its in the system. If its not there now it cant be restored. Only if its acting wonky (not normal), will a reset work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if there are any of the other Google apps (GApps) installed. Most likely if the Play Store isn't installed then the rest of the GApps package is either. The Nexus 7 happens to be very easy to work with, so don't worry.

[GApps Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2589167) will be the tool that will be used. The link will describe the toolkit in detail as well as any fixes that have been made.

The Play Store - [GApps Manager download](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itslightness.gappsmanager).

The tool will be able to show android version, so you won't have to search. This will show all the packages available. The directions are easy to follow. Once complete you'll have the Play Store installed.

The only thing that might cause any hiccups is if you are on a custom ROM, which usually don't have GApps included because of legalities. Then you would find out what ROM and version, then go to the developers website and download the correct GApps from there. The custom ROMs will conflict with stock GApps.